# Possible to revert the value in a textbox?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have two textboxes, value in textbox1 gets added to the value in textbox2 and i have this coding in place, the only problem i have is that if i made an error when adding a value in textbox1 and i remove the value to add the correct value the textbox2 value does not also change to the previous value so the calculations become wrong. My coding so far.

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim Value1, Value2 As Decimal

    Decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, Value1)
    Decimal.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, Value2)

    TextBox2.Text = (Value1 + Value2).ToString
End Sub
```

So ideally what i was looking for was help so when i remove the value in textbox1 or just change it to 0 then the original value is that was displayed in textbox2 reappears? hope that makes sense.

Comment: Why don't you do this calculation on `leave` event?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  I thought it would be best to have it in the textxhanged event as this is most suited to when the text changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the value of textbox2 in a separate field and do the calculation based on that value.

i.e

may be in `formload` get the TextBox2 value to a variable

```
dim txt2val as decimal 
Decimal.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, txt2val)
```

then

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim Value1

    Decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, Value1)

    TextBox2.Text = (Value1 + txt2val).ToString
End Sub
```